# Split an Array of Objects to Multiple objects

Tags: arrays, powershell

I wanted to split the output of the following command:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $array = get-vm | Select-Object 
    @{Name="VMName";Expression=$_.name}},
    @{Name='VirtualNetwork';e={ $_.VirtualNetworkAdapters | Foreach-Object{
        $_.VirtualNetwork}}},
    @{Name='PhysicalMACAddress';e={$_.VirtualNetworkAdapters| Foreach-Object{
        $_.physicaladdress}}}
```

whose output is like

[image: Default output]

to an output like this, can some one please help.

[image: Required Output]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you're in the wrong direction. You'd have to get all objects first, check for the one with most virtual networks, and create objects with a lot of VirtualNetworkN properties.